# SQL - join three table with "where" clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to write an SP that I will use in my c# program. I have three tables: Table1 (id pk, name, ...), Table2 (id PK, name, ...) and Table3((idT1,idT2) PK FK). So, Table3 models the n:n relationship between Table1 and Table2.

I want to retrieve all the Table2.name(s) related to a single Table1.name.

I have already tried to write a query with two inner join

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE slct
    @name nvarchar(50)

    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT Table2.name from Table2  
    join Table3 on Table2.id = Table3.idT2 join Table1 on Table1.id = Table3.idT1 where Table1.name = '%'+@name+'%'

    END
    GO

Table1
|1|abc|
|2|def|

Table2
|1|xyz|
|2|mno|

Table3
|1|1|
|1|2|
|2|2|
```

As result, I see more records than are needed. I expected a list of Table2.name related to a single Table1.name (specified by @name parameter)

*sorry for my english.*

Comment: Ops, I am using SQL Server

Comment: share sample data

Comment: Don't you mean `where Table.name LIKE '%'+@name+'%'`? Also, which table is `Table` in your where clause?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I forgot a '1'. Table is Table1

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin done

Comment: Use subquery to select top 1 record and then join the tables, or you can use the `CROSS APPLY` instead of subquery

Comment: @Voodoo can you post an example please?

Comment: Side note: I noticed you have this in the WHERE clause `Table1.name = '%'+@name+'%'`. I am thinking you are trying to use the wild card `%` and not the literal character `%`. In that case you need to use `LIKE` and *not* `=`. `Table1.name LIKE '%'+@name+'%'`

Comment: @Igor sorry but I want something like Table1.name = 'SOMETHING SPECIFIC'. I can use Like or not?

Comment: The way your code is now: If @name has the value `SOMETHING SPECIFIC` then your code now searches for an exact match `%SOMETHING SPECIFIC%` meaning no wild cards it must match that string and be surrounded by percent characters. If you change it to LIKE the percent signs turn into wild card characters and then `Table1.name` must *contain* the string `SOMETHING SPECIFIC` anywhere in the value. If you want an exact match of `Table1.name` must equal `SOMETHING SPECIFIC` then remove the `%` on either side that you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Table2.Names from Table2 
inner join 
     (select Table3.idT1 as SubQueryID1, Table3.idT2 as SubQueryID2 
      from Table3 inner join Table1 on Table1.id = Table3.idT1) 
on 
Table2.Id = SubQueryID2
```

Comment: Thanks. Between "(" and ")" I added where Table1.name = @name

Comment: `SELECT distinct Table2.nome from Table2
 inner join(select Table3.idT1 as SubQuery1, Table3.idT2 as SubQuery2 
 from Table3 inner join Table1 as t1 on t1.id = Table3.idT1 where t1.nome = @nome) 
 as V on V.SubQuery2 = Table2.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Table2.name 

FROM Table2  
    INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.id = Table3.idT2 
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.id = Table3.idT1 
    ) t

WHERE 
    Table1.name = '%'+@name+'%'
```

Comment: Hello, always try to attach more information for the answer then just plain text. Some comments are usually useful describe what should do the OP differently, how to solve this, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to retrieve all the Table2.name(s) related to a single Table1.name.

```
select t2.name
from table2 t2 join
     table3 t3
     on t3.idT2 = t2.id
group by t2.name
having count(*) = 1;
```

This returns names in `t2` that have only one row in `table3`.  This makes two assumptions (both of which are reasonable for this data structure):

- Names are unique in `table1` and `table2`.
- Pairs are unique in `table3`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to retrieve all the Table2.name(s) related to a single Table1.name.

Your query actually has the right join logic. You have to clarify the scope of the where clause.

- `Table1.Name` *contains* `@name`: you need the like operator instead of the equal operator.
- `Table1.Name` *strictly* equals to `@name`: you have to remove the wildcards.

See below two examples:

```
select distinct T2.Name
from Table1 as T1
inner join Table3 as T3 on T3.IDT1 = T1.ID
inner join Table2 as T2 on T2.ID = T3.IDT2
where T1.Name like '%'+@name+'%'
```

or

```
select distinct T2.Name
from Table1 as T1
inner join Table3 as T3 on T3.IDT1 = T1.ID
inner join Table2 as T2 on T2.ID = T3.IDT2
where T1.Name = @name
```